# How do I run a javascript function defined by the website via the Shortcuts ios app?

Tags: javascript, ios, function, shortcut

I'm trying to use my garage door's remote server website in order to open my garage from my iPhone. The website's javascript has a function GarageDoor(), where if I type GarageDoor(1) into the Google Chrome console the garage door will open.

I'm using the ios Shortcuts app with the 'run Javascript on Webpage' feature. I have the following code:

```
GarageDoor(1);
completion(result);
```

If I type this, I only get the response "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GarageDoor". How do I access the website's GarageDoor() function?

Cheers

Comment: I am not sure how the Shortcuts app works but could it be possible the webpage did not entirely finish loading and the `GarageDoor` function is not yet available? You could for example add a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) around your code to give it more time to load.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/shortcuts/apd218e2187d/3.2/ios/13.2
says "The input to the Run JavaScript on Webpage action must be an active Safari webpage, which means you must run the shortcut from the share sheet (specifically from Safari, SFSafariViewController or ASWebAuthenticationSession)."